# How to cancel UIPanGestureRecognizer when UIPinchGestureRecognizer is performed?

Tags: swift, uikit

I have 2 gestures that I added to my custom view. One of them is a pan gesture and the other is a pinch gesture. I want to make the pan gesture fail when a pinch gesture is detected and performed. Based on the documentation, I can use the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`'s `shouldRequireFailOf` method like this:

```
public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if gestureRecognizer == myPanGestureRecognizer && otherGestureRecognizer == myPinchGestureRecognizer {
        return true
    }
        
    return false
}
```

This is what I did and unfortunately, it just make the pan gesture disabled and I can only do the pinch gesture.

Then I tried limiting the number of touches on the selector method, because for the pan gesture it only requires 1 touch to perform it and for the pinch it requires 2 fingers. This is what I did:

```
@objc func didPan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    guard sender.numberOfTouches == 1 else { return }

    switch sender.state {
       // Do something...
    }
}

@objc func didPinch(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    guard sender.numberOfTouches == 2 else { else }
    
    switch sender.state {
        // Do something...
    }
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

For most of the times it works well but sometimes it has a weird behavior when the user performs a pinch gesture and finish the gesture, it will stop at `.changed` state where it should've stop at `.ended` or `.cancelled` and for my case it will do some weird behavior for the UI.

Is there any other way to prefer one gesture over another? FYI, I tried to implement this for a pan gesture and double tap gesture and it works well (using the `shouldRequireFailOf` method). But for some reason it just doesn't work with pan and pinch gestures.

Comment: after initializing the gestures use ```myPanGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: myPinchGestureRecognizer)``` .  Read the discussion here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624203-require

Comment: @udi it's the same as using the `shouldRequireFailOf` method. The pan gesture is disabled